# How to store a map or json object as a property in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying store a map or json object as a property in Neo4j, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's a limitation of node properties right now. You have a few workarounds to choose from.

1. You can turn your json object into a string and save it as a property. You can use [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.convert/) to convert JSON strings to and from Cypher map objects.
2. You can instead save the map properties as properties on the node, though that loses the grouping you would get from the object itself.
3. If #2 isn't enough, you could also alter your graph model so the data in the JSON object corresponds to graph objects, nodes and properties related to the original node.

Comment: thanks so much. T used apoc.convert.getJsonProperty() for converting to object  when get data and apoc.convert.toJson(map) for storing data

Comment: I spent far too long working out a similar problem ( scalar type JSON in graphql ). In the hopes that it may help others... If you have JSON data, an object and not a quoted string. Then you can use `apoc.text.toCypher($value)` to set and `apoc.convert.fromJsonMap(value)` to get.

Answer (score 2):

Storing a map as properties is supported by neo java OGM library. The library will unwind your map to graph node properties if you annotate the java class field with @Properties.

Class:

```
@NodeEntity
public class DataNode {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Properties
    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, String> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

How to use in java:

```
    DataNode data = new DataNode();
    data.getMap().put("testKey", "keyvalue");
    data.getMap().put("myKey", "key value for my key");
```

How it will look in neo:

[image]

Notice that if you end up using map keys with dot ".", you might get funky side effects when loading the entity from neo => nested maps. Consider then changing the delimiter in @Properties or change the key.

Comment: I have tried the same thing. but now I am unable to delete the property from the node. because its not supported by neo4j cost planner yet.


Suppose in your case how would you remove map.myKey from this node?

Comment: thx pawan for confirmation of issue. Another story is how OGM handles nested maps, I mean map of maps...