# Can we create two dimensional array as node property?

Tags: arrays, neo4j, cypher

I am a newbie to Neo4j and I'm modeling my requirements. Can someone confirm, if a by-dimensional array can be created as a node property? And how costly is such property retrieval?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store a map or json object as a property in neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364282/how-to-store-a-map-or-json-object-as-a-property-in-neo4j)

Answer (score 4):

It cannot be created. If you try, the error message even tells the limitations:

```
CREATE (node:SomeLabel {prop: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]})
```

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError
>
> Collections containing collections can not be stored in properties.

Interestingly, there is another error message that you can get (at least in 3.2.6) if you add a list of just one element:

```
CREATE (node:SomeLabel {prop: [[1, 2]]})
```

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError
>
> Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof

Note that this is a limitation of the *data model*. However, the Cypher *query language* allows you to creat n-dimensional arrays. Hence, this is a perfectly valid Cypher query:

```
RETURN [[1, 2], [3, 4]] AS x
```

Comment: Thank you. And would be curious if Neo4j is planning to enhance array data type in near future.

Comment: Good question, but I have no idea whether they plan to change this. In any case, you can work around it pretty well in almost all practical applications.